# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.user')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[I got this error while trying to run this Application. I am not sure what is wrong but any help would be appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGGkj.jpg)

Here's the Code.

**Routes.js**

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {AuthContext} from './AuthProvider';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import AppStack from './AppStack';
const Routes = () => {
const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
}, []);

if (initializing) return null;


return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
);
}
export default Routes;
```

**AuthProvider.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

return(
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            user,
            setUser,
            login: async (email, password) => {
                try {
                    await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            register: async (email, password) => {
                try {
                    await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            logout: async () => {
                try {
                    await auth().signOut();
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
        }}> {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Providers from './navigation';


const App = () => {

  return <Providers />;

}

export default App;
```

I have tried looking for similar problems but so far nothing came up. It might be a stupid mistake that i might have overlooked but please do correct me.

Comment: It feels like you might be using the `useContext` incorrectly - try just setting the context to something like `const userContext = useContext(AuthContext);`? If you then `console.log` the `userContext` what object structure do you see?

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error
I think its because i forgot to wrap the component(in which i am using context values) with contextProvider

Comment: Yes, this solved it for me. I am wrapping my components in App.js.  After creating the context provider, I forgot to wrap my components with it